# 'pub get' has not been run in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, dart-pub

I installed flutter and dart now I saw an error in android studio('Pub get' has not been run). How can I solve this problem?

```
Working dir: C:\Users\jhon\Desktop\FluxStore 1.3.5-woo\source
"C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat" get
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: git fetch
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Process finished with exit code 69
```

Comment: did you run `flutter doctor`? or did you set plugin on the android studio?

Answer (score 3):

**Prerequisites**

It would be best if you can describe how you install your Flutter or Dark SDK in your post. Otherwise, please ensure the you followed the instructions here:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install
- https://dart.dev/get-dart

**Suggestion**

When you are trying to create a project, try to run the following:

**For Flutter**

```
flutter packages get
```

**For Dart**

```
pub get packages
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the dependencies or update them, for android studio 4.4, along the error onthe right side there are two buttons one for get the dependencies and another for update the dependencies, just click on the one for get the dependencies and it will work.